# Only one canvas shows when making canvases in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make two separate canvases in tkinter however only one is showing.

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

root.title('Title')
root.geometry('500x600')

left_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=500, height=600)
left_canvas.pack()
left_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 600 ,125 ,0 , fill='#c595d2')

right_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=500, height=600)
right_canvas.pack()
right_canvas.create_rectangle(375, 600 ,500 ,0 , fill='black')
```

Comment: The root window is not large enough to show second canvas, try making the root window taller.

Answer (score 0):

You have the geometry = 500 x 600 and your first canvas is also of 500x600 so there is no place left for the second canvas in the main window.
You should adjust the size so that both can fit in the main window.

Comment: Oh that makes sense the thing is when I tried making my canvas smaller I couldn't move it to the side so I assumed they were meant to overlap but ig i'll just figure that out thanks for the help :)